# How to solve phpmyadmin error?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb, centos7, apache2.4

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on my server but I am receiving errors:

> Error: php70u-common conflicts with
>   php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
>
> Error: php70u-json conflicts with
>   php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I am using Centos 7, have epel installed and when I try to use `yum -y install phpmyadmin`, I receive the above error. How to resolve this?

Comment: It appears you are trying to install phpmyadmin by using an RPM that was built for PHP 5.4, while you have PHP 7.0 installed on the server. Just download the tarball of phpmyadmin and install it manually.

Comment: Wring versions conflict at the face of errors

Comment: Your problem is same as this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246339/can-not-install-phpmyadmin-error-php71w-common-conflicts-with-php-common-5-4-16