# Cannot install phpMyAdmin Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, installation, centos7

I just installed CentOS 7 and PHP 7.1xx and MySQL but impossible to install phpMyAdmin. I have an error message but no answer on Google yes only one answer but which itself gives me the same error message.

```
rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

> Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: `yum remove php5.4.16`

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: php5.4.16
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Wow, figure out the real name and remove that name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't install it directly by YUM either. As I remember, The problem is using CentOS 7 or php7 (in my case).

But you can solve your problem by access here: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/
then download any version you want, and config a little (decompress and copy that folder into /var/www/html/, ...), then you can use phpMyAdmin as normal.